# P&T Switch value

Tags: pixelandtonic, switch

I have a field named {the_shadow} set up with P&T Switch field type of "yes" and "no" for their values. For some reason it doesn't seem to work:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="portfolio_work"
    orderby="random"
    limit="20"
    disable="member_data|pagination|categories|categories_fields"
}
    {if main_photo}
    <!-- Work -->
        <li class="touchcarousel-item">          
            <div class="workPiece">{exp:gwcode_fileinfo:single file="{main_photo}"}<img src="{main_photo}" width="{image_width}" height="505" alt="{title}" />{/exp:gwcode_fileinfo:single}</div>
            {if the_shadow == "yes"}<div class="workShadow">&nbsp;</div>{/if}

    </li>
        {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I am running ee v.2.5.5.

Thanks,
-Sam

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what doesn't work? What have you tried so far? For more details about what to include in your question, see our [FAQ](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  You'll see that pt_switch actually outputs 'y' not 'yes'. :)  If you're having trouble with conditionals. always echo out your variables so you can see what you need to test against. :)

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="pt_test_channel"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
    {pt_switch}
    {if pt_switch == 'y'}
    yessirreebob
    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So in your case you need this line:

```
{if the_shadow == "y"}<div class="workShadow">&nbsp;</div>{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks, Lisa.

I did a test above and it works. The weird thing is when it won't work when it's set to default yes but once it's been toggled, then it works.  On the test channel it works for both though. I'm just glad it's working. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Hrm, you have to toggle it to register? Can you make sure you're running the version from GitHub? https://github.com/pixelandtonic/pt_switch  Thank you!